# How to open a PHP file with a JS or HTML Editor in Eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, interface, ide

I normally open a file with it's default editor. Thus a .php file is opened in the default PHP editor and treated like a PHP file.

However, often the code in my PHP files contains a lot of JS or HTML. In these cases it would be nice to open such PHP files using a JS or HTML Editor. Right now, this is a pain since I have to click on `Open With -> Other` and then choose the JS or HTML Editor.

Is there a way to add the JS or HTML editor as an option to the `Open With` menu ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the PHP file type to Content types. Go into Eclipse Preferences `General > Content Types`

[image]

1. Choose `JavaScript Source File` in Content Types and,
2. In the `File associations` click `Add` and add `*.php` like so :

[image]

Then in the Open With menu for php files, the JS Editor should start appearing like so :

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much :) Wil try the solution now. it is a bit difrent on my eclipse version but il try :) the work space is now formating Q_Q....

Comment: Cool. If you have any questions comment back. If you get it working according to my answer, please consider accepting it by clicking on the 'Tick' mark next to it like so : http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png.

Comment: I did as you instructed. But still no luck. I menaged to over come this inconvinience by placing all y js code inside a js file for now. but the new version is terible for js code... any code inserted trigers like 40 sec lock of the aplication. Unusable still...