# Eclipse PDT Crashing with a simple code

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

This is one of the most weird issues I had with `Eclipse`.
I tried in two different machines, also downloaded a new copy of `Eclipse` from their website and still having the same problem.

If you open Eclipse, create the file: `test.php`, copy the code below, then save, then close, and then try to open that file again, you will see the error on the image below.

> Failed to create the part's controls

I don't know why, it is very strange.

Is there anything I could do to stop this behaviour?

It is part of a very bigger problem. I had to simplify it to this code to give you reproducible step by step directions.

**Here the code:**

```
<script>
<??>
//
<??>
```

**Here the error:**

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11983973/how-to-open-a-php-file-with-a-js-or-html-editor-in-eclipse

Comment: thanks @Shridhar, that solves my problem partially because I can open the document, but I need to open it with the PHP editor and not other kind of editors.

Comment: Try switching to other workspace but selecting the same workspace again. That will restart your eclipse.

Comment: did that with no success

Comment: try latest nightly build, I didn't notice such problem there - http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/latest-nightly/